# How to return definite element whose index matches the index of the element I'm looking for?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I look in column `time_to_receive` for is the same time as I need, for ex: '20:33' and I need to return 'business' from `category` and username, how can I do it?

[Image of DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jo5xc.png) 
Now I find matching elements  and get all the column

```
   for x in mycol.find({ f"time_to_receive.{i}": { '$elemMatch': {'$eq': time}}})
```

Comment: Please provide the code you have tried so far along with sample input and expected output.

Comment: It's really unclear from an image what the actual document structure is, please use the `mongo` shell to display the document and use the "text" in your question instead of an image. Please then also show the **expected result** of your query. You *might* be saying that you wan the same "matching index" from the other array  in the document.  But without **clear** examples using **"text"** and not images, then it's really unclear and not answerable. Please edit the question to make it clearer.